# Yii2: Customize the wrapper div.form-group for a single $form->textInput()

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

When I add the class in the template of the form. All form-groups appear with the assigned class:

**`/views/user/_form.php`**

```php
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;


$disabled_user = !$model->assign_user?'disabled':'';

?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
    'fieldClass' => 'app\components\form\FormGroupWidget',
    'fieldConfig' => ['options' => ['class' => 'form-group label-floating']],
]); ?>
```

But when I do it in the widget template, not all of them come up with the class that I assigned.

**`/components/form/FormGroupWidget.php`**

```php
namespace app\components\form;

use yii\widgets\ActiveField;
use yii\web\View;

class FormGroupWidget extends ActiveField{
    public function textInput( $options = []){

        $this->template ='{label}
                            {input}
                            <div class="error">{error}{hint}
                            </div>
                ';

        $this->form->fieldConfig['options']['class'] = 'form-group label-floating';

        return parent::textInput($options);
    }
}
```

I want to configure everything in the widget and not in the form template. I do not understand why it does not work in the widget. The first input text does not have my class and the others do have it:

**`Result HTML`**

```php
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">No. de identificación</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="UserForm[identification_number]">
</div>

<div class="form-group label-floating">
  <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="UserForm[name]">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `$options` rather than overriding the `$form->fieldConfig` if you look into the docs for the `$options` in the `ActiveField`

> @var array the HTML attributes (name-value pairs) for the field
>   container tag. The values will be HTML-encoded using
>   [[Html::encode()]]. If a value is `null`, the corresponding attribute
>   will not be rendered. The following special options are recognized:
>
> - `tag`: the tag name of the container element. Defaults to `div`. Setting it to `false` will not render a container tag. See also
>     [[\yii\helpers\Html::tag()]].
>
> If you set a custom `id` for the container element, you may need to
>   adjust the [[$selectors]] accordingly.

Which means you can even specify the `tag` other than `div` if you want for the container element in the form of `name=>value` pairs.

Also, you should call the parent function and then override your settings and return `$this` from your function, change the function to the following

```
public function textInput( $options = [] ) {
    parent::textInput ( $options );
    $this->template = '{label}
                        {input}
                        <div class="error">{error}{hint}
                        </div>
            ';
    $this->options=['class'=>'form-group label-floating']
    return $this;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Perfect! That's how it works. I do not know why I did not try it this way. Thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome my friend @ArturoVerbelDeLeón happy to help